# How do I automatically update hundreds of images in an HTML page using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML page where I want to refresh a lot of images every 30 seconds after the HTML page has been downloaded. I understand how to do this with Jquery and a single image, but I want to use about 200 custom urls to determine the current image to display for over 200 images. I need to find an efficient way to have jquery call the custom url associated with each image to download the url for the needed image as it changes, and then update the image in the page when it changes.

Current hyperlink example to demonstrate the custom urls.

```
<A href="/urlThatReturnsCurrentImageURL/1234/4567">link to url for image</A>
```

Each custom url will return an image tag like this (or any other text that makes this simpler for jquery)

```
<img src="/static/someImage.jpg">
```

What is the simplest way to have jquery call the custom url for each image to download the image url, image html, or some other text that jquery can use to download the right image every 30 seconds? Please keep in mind that I will have about 200 of these on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a DIV for each link and make the url to call the DIV id. Then if you make each DIV part of the same class, you can then iterate through the DIVs of that class and call each url.

```
                <div id='true.txt' class='isSolvedImage'>
                    <img src="_images/solved.png">
                </div>

                <div id='false.txt' class='isSolvedImage'>
                    <img src="_images/solved.png">
                </div>

    <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>            
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('img').hide();
    function updateImages() {
                    var getDivs = 0;
                    //iterate div with class isSolvedImage
                    $("div.isSolvedImage").each(function() {
                        var img = $(this).find('img');
                        // send ajax requrest
                        $.get(this.id, function(data) {       
                            if(data == 1){
                               img.show();
                            }
                            else{
                               img.hide();
                            }
                        });
                      });
                }
    setInterval("updateImages()", 30000);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper on the server side that returns all URLs at once. You can then lookup each image in the returned object (I'd recommend using JSON for this).

Comment: One of the main objectives of the approach is to not determine the results of the URLs all at once but rather execute them each individually as the Javascript calls back to determine the correct image for each url.

Comment: I don't understand why. You need to replace all images every 30 seconds, so why should you fire up 200 requests at once instead of just one? But if you definitely need 200 requests, there is no efficient way to do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the images

$(document).ready(function(){

```
setTimeout(function(){

   $('img .reloadable').each(function(){
        orginal = $(this).attr('src');

        if(original.indexOf('?') == -1)
        {
           original = original + '?' + Math.random(); 
        }else if(original.indexOf('&') == -1)
        {
           original = original + '&t=' + Math.random();
        }
        $(this).attr('src',original);
   })

},30000) // 30 seconds
```

})

Using the random with create a new uri as its different to the previous one, so the dom will reload it as its not currently cached !

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would just be to use a full page refresh:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />`

You can use the same code to refresh individual elements, just by specifying the id.
This is probably the easiest solution to have it update on the front end of the page.